# MySQL returning broken images

Tags: php, mysql, sql

over the last couple of days I've been working on a application that let's a user upload a image and store the image in my filesystem and the file path in my database. I'm almost done but i have come across a brick wall.

The image gets uploaded to my filesystem and the file path stored in my database just fine. put when i go to the page that displays the images. it returns them as
"broken images"

here's the code that is giving me trouble

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>OurFile's  Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require("pdoconn.php");
//img_path is the column in my DB that holds the image URL.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT img_path FROM ourimages");
$stmt->execute();
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
echo '<br><img src="' . $result['img_path'] . '" />';
}
$conn = null;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appropriated.

Thank you for your future responses 
i edited the code. using ed and jay's suggestions...but its still
output the same result

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database. What are the columns in your database?

Comment: ya i suppose i worded the title wrong

Comment: the columns are imgid, img_name, img_path, and img_type. imgid is primaary key and A.I. while the other three are varchar 255

Comment: MySQL is **NOT** outputting "broken images". You are using mysql incorrectly and generating INVALID html `src` attributes for your `<img>` tags. That's not mysql's problem. That's yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
```

because you're using `$value` to loop over every column in the table. The `src` attribute needs to be a URL, but I'm guessing only one column in your `ourimages` table holds a URL. You're outputting an image for *every* column thanks to this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ourimages"); // gets every column
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
foreach ($result as $value) // uses every column
{
```

The simple fix is to change your SQL:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT whateverColumnHasTheURL FROM ourimages");
```

Then use that column like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $result->whateverColumnHasTheURL; ?>" />
```

Or, you can use the `SELECT * ...`, but just use the one column in the `<img>` tag:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ourimages");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
echo "<br>";?> <img src="<?php echo $result->whateverColumnHasTheURL; ?>" /><?php
```

---

Note: If you're actually trying to loop over the rows, you need to put `$stmt->fetch` in a loop, as in `while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);) { echo... }`

Comment: thank you to ed and jay. i changed the code to   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT img_path FROM ourimages"); and while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
    echo '<br><img src="' . $result['img_path'] . '" />';
}
$conn = null; but sadly its still the same result

Comment: @Strangercode Take a look at the generated HTML code, is the path to the image correct?

Comment: Yes Charlotte, when i inspected the element. it highlights the path name and read and the hove text says "couldn't load this image". and yes its the coreect path.

Comment: @Strangercode If the generated HTML is correct, then you are having a totally different problem, perhaps related to file permissions or whether your web server (e.g., Apache, nginx, etc.) has access to the folder where you store the images. You should accept one of the answers posted here and ask a different question if you're stuck on why the generated HTML is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `foreach` loop to output the results of the query is an interesting way of doing things. Most folks use a `while` loop like this:

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
    echo '<br><img src="' . $result['column_with_image_path'] . '" />';
}
```

Since you're selecting all of the columns from your table you need to be specific about the identifier you use in the image tag.